# Text moves itself center after CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have some misbehaving text in a CSS animation.

The text appears to "type" itself out, and then end with a blinking cursor. It does this well, but when it's done typing a line that line tends to "float" or "shift" itself over to the center of the page.

I am centering the text with `text-align: center;` as well as with a flexbox (to get it center of the page).

[Here's a link to a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqL564j7/)

And here's some code:

```
    html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


.do-you-even-flexbox, .content {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.content {
    padding:8px 20px 15px;
    display:flex;
    align-content:center;
}
.box {
    height:20%;
    margin:auto

}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.content h1 {
    white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-animation: typing 5s steps(60, end);
  -moz-animation: typing 5s steps(60, end);
}
.content h2 {
    white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-animation: typing 5s steps(60, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
  -moz-animation: typing 5s steps(60, end);
  -moz-animation-delay:4s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
}

.content h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: typing 10s steps(120, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation: typing 10s steps(120, end);
  -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;

}

span {
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  to { opacity: .0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
    to { opacity: .0; }
}
```

And here's some HTML that goes with it:

```
<i class="do-you-even-flexbox"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="box">
        <h1>This wasn't the same as the fiddle code.</p>
        <h2>So I've removed some details so it's similar to the fiddle.</p>
        <h3>~<a href="contact.html"> get in touch </a>~<a href="about.html"> about me </a>~<a href="blog/"> blog </a>~<a href="projects.html"> projects </a>~<a href="portfolio/"> my portfolio </a>~<span> |</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @NenadVracar will edit for clarity as well: After the animation is complete, the text floats itself (or nudges itself?) to be centered, instead of starting from it's final position. How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: The effect is a little more pronounced if you give the `h1` a border like `border: 1px solid green;`

Answer (score 1):

well, the problem seems to be with the animation from 0 to 100%, since Heading tags are blocks, and blocks always are 100% percent from its container, the animation actually goes from 0 to the total width of the page. What you are trying to do here its a little bit tricky but can be done nesting a tag inside every Heading tag and animating that tag while giving each heading tag inline behavior which ensures the width is not 100% of the container but just the text.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


.do-you-even-flexbox, .content {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.content {
    padding:8px 20px 15px;
    display:flex;
    align-content:center;
}
.box {
    height:20%;
    margin:auto
    text-align: center;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

h1 span {
  font-size: 75px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0em;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

h2 span {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

h3 span {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.content h1 span {
 white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps(60, end);
  -moz-animation: typing 2s steps(60, end);
}
.content h2 {
 white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps(60, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
  -moz-animation: typing 2s steps(60, end);
  -moz-animation-delay:2s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
}

.content h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: typing 10s steps(120, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation: typing 2s steps(120, end);
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;

}

span.caret {
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  to { opacity: .0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
    to { opacity: .0; }
}
```

```html
<i class="do-you-even-flexbox"></i>
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">

    <h1><span>This</span></h1>
    <br>
    <h2><span>This is a subtitile</span></h2>
    <br>
    <h3><span>These are links to things on other pages.<span class="caret">|</span> </span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```